# Invisible folder after usage of trash-cli

Tags: terminal, finder, trash, macos

Recently, I decided to install [trash-cli](https://github.com/andreafrancia/trash-cli) on my MacBook Pro after using it successfully on my Ubuntu machine. To set it up I ran the following commands.

```
git clone https://github.com/andreafrancia/trash-cli.git
sudo python setup.py install
```

After installation, I decided to delete a folder using `trash-put`. So I run `trash-put ~/anaconda/`. However, this folder has never arrived in my `.Trash` folder, yet it disappeared from my Finder (see below, sorry for the mess of files).

[image: Screenshot of Finder in Terminal run with <code>ls -a</code>]

So far so good, the folder disappeared. However, when running `locate anaconda` in a Terminal window the folder Anaconda is still there (only the first couple of lines are shown in the screenshot below).

[image: Screenshot of Finder in Terminal run with <code>locate anaconda</code>]

Now, my question is whether any of you guys could have an idea on how I can delete this folder or at least make it re-appear in my Finder?

So far, I've tried restarting my MacBook without success. I've also tried to run `rm /Users/admin/anaconda` which failed, too.

Running 10.10.1 on a MacBook Pro Mid-2012. I do have administrator rights and full access to all files.

---

**UPDATE 1**

1. `rm` output

   rm: anaconda: No such file or directory
2. `felix` and `admin` are the same user. I have renamed it for my own convenience purposes, but they are **the same**!

Comment: Why did you think that a CLI tool for the XORG environment would work on a Mac?? What exactly was the result when you tried the `rm` command for the folder? I also note that your `ls -a` and `locate` commands show you (Felix) as the user but the search result shows the `anaconda` directory located in the user `admin`'s directory.??

Comment: @douggro I've had it installed on my Mac before. I think under Mountain Lion.

Comment: MacPorts includes the `rmtrash` command line utility, which uses the native OS X trash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have seen by running `ls` and `rm` (and viewing in Finder), the `/Users/admin/anaconda` folder and its contents are no longer present in the filesystem.

`locate` uses a database that is updated approximately once a week in OS X, so deleting a file/folder and immediately (or even later that day or week) using `locate` will not reflect its removal.

You can manually update the `locate` database by running this command:

```
sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb
```

See the [locate.updatedb(8) man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/locate.updatedb.8.html) for further information.